# Left shift operator, linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Define $S$ to be the left shift operator from $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ to $\mathbb{C}^\infty$. Describe the kernel of $S^2-S-I$, what is ts dimension? Give a Jordan basis of S for the restriction to this kernel.

I know that $(S^2-S-I)(s,t,u,v,w,\dots)=(u-t-s,v-u-t,w-v-u,\dots)$

And also that the Fibonacci sequence $(1,1,2,3,5,\dots)$ is in the kernel.

I have a feeling that the dimension is $2$ but how do I find a basis for this?

Answer (score 3):

You have $(a_k)\in\ker(f)$ if and only if $a_{k+2}=a_{k+1}+a_k$. So any such sequence is determined by its first two terms.

$$(a,b,a+b, a+2b,2a+3b, 3a+5b,....) = a(1,0,1,1,2,3,5,...) + b(0,1,1,2,3,5,...)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Let $p(t) = t^2 - t -1$.  Note that $p(t) = (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)$ where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues
$$
t = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
Note that $\ker p(S) = \ker(S - \lambda_1 I) + \ker(S - \lambda_2 I)$.